# Modprobe not working

Tags: drivers

So I did

```
modprobe ./speakup_dummy.ko
```

in drivers/staging/speakup directory and didn't get any error message. However when I check with

```
lsmod | grep "speakup"
```

the module hasn't been loaded. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let linux manage the process of determining which version of the module to load, as it must be the one for the kernel you are running. So, from any directory, just do (and for example):

```
$ lsmod | grep "speakup"
$ sudo modprobe speakup_dummy
[sudo] password for doug:
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'speakup_dummy': No such device
$ lsmod | grep "speakup"
speakup               102400  0
$
```

Comment: Okay but why is it giving the error could not insert 'speakup_dummy' ?

Comment: I assumed because I don't actually have compatible hardware, or becuase my computer is a server. Most typically, I load the "msr" module, which works fine.